# Loading javascript file depending on window size

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>275)
     {
        $('.navbar-left').fadeIn();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.navbar-left').fadeOut();
     }
 });
```

to show my logo on my navbar when scrolled down. The problem is I want to disable this script when the window size is at 768px. I understand I could use:

```
if ( $(window).width() > 768) {      
  //Add your javascript for large screens here 
} 
else {
  //Add your javascript for small screens here 
}
```

However, I do not program javascript so this is very difficult for me to integrate into my existing code. Could someone kindly help?

I have attempted so I do not get MARKED DOWN.

```
if ( $(window).width() > 768) {

 if ($(this).scrollTop()>275)
     {
        $('.navbar-left').fadeIn();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.navbar-left').fadeOut();
     }
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```js
(function(){
  $(window).scroll(()=>{
    if(window.innerWidth <= 768){
      if($(window).scrollTop() > 10){ //<- set to number you need
        $('.navbar-left').fadeOut();
      }
      else{
        $('.navbar-left').fadeIn();
      }
    }
  });
}())
```

```css
.wrapper{ height: 100px; } /* you may need this to prevent jankiness */
.navbar-left{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
.push {
  height: 1000px; /* just to test scrolling with no content */
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar-left">navbar left</div>
</div>
<div class="push"></div>
    
    
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you!